# How to get Data from SQLite base on interval

Tags: sqlite, winrt-xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Say, I have the below SQLite DB :

DataType:

```
DateTime                Int            
(with HH:MM:SS)         Queue Size

2016-08-15 06:10:10         20          
2016-08-15 06:11:12         30          
2016-08-15 06:12:16         10          
2016-08-15 06:13:12         10          
2016-08-15 06:14:10         60 

2016-08-15 06:15:08         20          
2016-08-15 06:16:10         30          
2016-08-15 06:17:12         10     
2016-08-15 06:18:11         10  
2016-08-15 06:19:12         10  

2016-08-15 06:20:12         10
```

1) How to get the total Queue for every 5 minute using SQL for creating data source for the chart?

example 
the 1st 5 minute , the total Queue is : 130 
the 2nd 5 minute , the total Queue is : 80

the 3rd 5 minute ?

```
2) I have this class for the Chart


public class Queue
{
    public DateTime  Interval { get; set; }
    public int Queue { get; set; }
}

private void LoadQueue()
{
  //-- how to use SQL to query the SQLite DB


  List<Queue> QList = new List<Queue>();


  //---code ---

 (ColumnChart.Series[0] as ColumnSeries).ItemsSource = QList;



}
```

The XAML for the chart:

```
 <Charting:Chart x:Name="ColumnChart" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="505,100,0,0" Width="399" Height="400">

   <Charting:ColumnSeries Title="Queue" Margin="0" 

IndependentValuePath="Interval" 
DependentValuePath="Queue" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>

    </Charting:Chart>
```

---------- Edit

```
public class tblQueue
 {
     public DateTime QueueDate { get; set; }       
     public int QueueSize { get; set; }

 }

Case : insert the data into SQLite DB using SQlite.Net-PCL

    var db = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath);

      var newItem = new tblQueue()
                {
                   a) QueueDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
                   b) QueueDate = DateTime.Now,

                    QueueSize = intQ_Length,

                };

                db.Insert(newItem);

Question :

1) what dataType should I use for my tblQueue class for table ?

which dataType to use?

1a)  public DateTime QueueDate { get; set; }   
1b)  public string QueueDate { get; set; }
```

------- Edit_2 :
base on the above SQLite DB:

1) say assume data is ok. This is the result I want to show after SQL-Select:

```
Interval every 5 minute     ttl Queue
----------------------      ------------
2016-08-15 06:15:00          150  

2016-08-15 06:20:00          70

2016-08-15 06:25:00


 <Charting:Chart x:Name="ColumnChart" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="253,100,0,0" Width="651" Height="506">

<Charting:ColumnSeries Title="WaitingLine" Margin="0" IndependentValuePath="Interval" 
DependentValuePath="Size" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>

</Charting:Chart>
```

I need the following for the chart:

2.1))IndependentValuepath ="Interval"  Example : 06:15

2.2)DependentValuePath ="Size:

DependentValuePath show : 150 , 70  For the y-axis

IndependentValuePath show the : 06:15  , 06:20 , 06:25 for x-axis

These values (2.1 & 2.2) come from below class

3) How to add a properties for Interval in this class Val?

```
public class Val
{
   ?? interval
   public int size { get; set; }
}
```

4) I dont seem to get the result for above Data by Interval as in (1)

```
private void LoadQueue()
{
    List<Val> ints=db.Query<Val>("SELECT sum(Queue) as 'size' from Queue group by (strftime('%Y%m%d%H0',QueueDate)+strftime('%M',QueueDate)/5)");  

}
```

Please note: I use QueueDate , Queue in the tblQueue,

Thanks

I am not sure my XAML is correct.  Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: anyone can offer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get the total Queue for every 5 minute using SQL for creating data source for the chart?

You can divide the `strftime('%M',Interval)` by 5 minutes and group by the result:

```
public class Val
{
   public int size { get; set; }
}

private void LoadQueue()
{
    // dont forget to replace the <TableName> with your SQLite table name
    List<Val> ints=db.Query<Val>("SELECT sum(Queue) as 'size' from <TableName> group by (strftime('%Y%m%d%H0', Interval)+strftime('%M',Interval)/5)");
    //now you can get the size for ints[0].size
    ...
    List<Queue> QList = new List<Queue>();

}
```

**Update for additional question:**

There are two ways to store the `DateTime`(`QueueDate = DateTime.Now`):

1. If you are using `new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath)` to get `SQLiteConnection` and create table. **The `DateTime` you are storing into SQLite is in format of Ticks(e.g. 636071680313888433)**. And when you get it, it is a UTC Time.
2. If you want to store `DateTime` in format of `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, **you need to use `new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPATH,false);`**, in which the false stands for `storeDateTimeAsTicks` argument. And it is default to true.(You will need to recreate the table and reinsert all the data if you already created the table in first way).

`QueueDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` will store the `DateTime` as a String.

**Update 2:**
If you also want to retrieve the date column, you can use the following codes:

```
public class Val
{
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   public int Size { get; set; }
}
private void LoadQueue()
{
    List<Val> ints = db.Query<Val>("SELECT min(QueueDate) as 'Date',sum(Queue) as 'Size' from tblQueue group by (strftime('%Y%m%d%H0',QueueDate)+strftime('%M',QueueDate)/5) order by Queuedate");

}
```

Comment: Xia:  Please have a look at my Edit. I m a bit confused what DataType to use for tblQueue Class which used by Sqlite.Net-PCL to insert DateTime into SQLite DB. please look at my db.Insert -statement. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer, please have a check. I think what you need is to use `new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPATH,false)`.

Comment: Xia: Really appreciate your help. What is Interval in the Select-statement, it is refer to QueueDate in my tblQueue? I will do a simulate Queue Data collection and use your methods. I will get back here and share my finding. Thanks

Comment: @ Xia: Please see my Edit_2

Comment: Yes, Interval refers to `QueueDate`. I've updated my answer to let the SQL statement also retrieve `QueueDate`. Please have a check.

Comment: @Xia: I am not able to get data from SQLite DB, I think the Problem is the SQLite.Net-PCL insert-method for datetime. To avoid confusion for this thread, I ask the question on SQLite.Net-PCL DateTime Insert on separate thread to clarify . pls visit here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076337/how-sqlite-net-pcl-insert-datetime-into-sqlite

Comment: @Xia: I used String for Date and time  in Queue Class and it works.