# How SQLite.Net-PCL insert DateTime into SQLite

Tags: sqlite, winrt-xaml, uwp

This class will be created as a table by SQLite.Net-PCL

```
 class Purchase
    {
        [SQLite.Net.Attributes.PrimaryKey, SQLite.Net.Attributes.AutoIncrement]
        public int QId { get; set; }
        public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to insert this date into this tblPurchase in SQLite DB.

```
strDate ="2016/08/10"   
strTime ="10:17:26"

string[] strAr_Date = strDate.Split('/');
string strYear = strAr_Date[0].ToString();
string strMth = strAr_Date[1].ToString();
string strDay = strAr_Date[2].ToString();
```

//-   Recreate Date base on DateTime.Now

```
 string strDateTime = strDay + "/" + strMth + "/" + strYear + " " + strTime;    
  DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strDateTime);
```

This dt will be inserted with below SQLite.Net-PCL :

```
 public static void InsertQueueData(string strContentA, string strContentB)
{
 var db = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath);

var newItem = new Purchase()
            {  
                PurchaseDate = dt,                
                Qty = 20
            };

            db.Insert(newItem);
}
```

Questions:

1) Is this dt ( PurchaseDate = dt) will be convert to SQLite Format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss by SQlite.Net-PCL when insert?

2) Can use this: 
  var db = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath);

Edit_2:

```
to use method(1) to insert a DateTime as below:

DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strDateTime);


The method must include :
var db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath,false);

(1)
public static void InsertQueueData(string strContentA, string strContentB)
{

var db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath,false);

var newItem = new Purchase()
   {  
     PurchaseDate = dt,                
              Qty = 20
    };

  db.Insert(newItem);
}

2) The purchase Class  must declare in this way :

class Purchase
 {
   [SQLite.Net.Attributes.PrimaryKey, SQLite.Net.Attributes.AutoIncrement]
   public int QId { get; set; }

   public string PurchaseDate { get; set; } // Dont use DateTime PurchaseDate

   public int Qty { get; set; }
 }





   Edit_3 <br/>

    public static string DBPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Purchase.sqlite");

    public static string strDbName = "Purchase.sqlite";

private void CreateDBNow()
{
 var DBPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Purchase.sqlite");
using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath))
  {
     conn.CreateTable<Purchase>();
 }

 }


        Please help. Thanks
```

InEdit_3

use : 
new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this dt ( PurchaseDate = dt) will be convert to SQLite Format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss by SQlite.Net-PCL when insert?

The answer is No. The `Datetime` will be convert to following format in SQLite:
[image]

I'm using [SQLite Toolbox](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1) to inspect the data.

If you want to convert the `DateTime` in format of `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. You need to use:

```
//false stands for 'storeDateTimeAsTicks'
//And the table need to be recreated if the table aready exists 
db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath,false);
```

Then the DateTime format in SQLite will be like this:
[image]

Comment: @Xia: Just to avoid the confusion, is my Edit_2 Explanation correct?

Comment: Yes, but you need to recreate your `Purchase` table using the new `db` that you get through `new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath,false);`.

Comment: @Xia: in Edit_3 : Is it Ok to use new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath)) without the false ?  Just to make sure.

Comment: No, it is not OK, if you want the `DateTime` to be in format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` in SQLite. As I decleared in answer, if you use that without false, the datetime will be a big integer in SQLite, thus you won't get correct result when you execute SQL statement.

Comment: But if you don't want the `DateTime` to be in format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` in SQLite, and don't want to execute SQL statement that depends on the datetime format. it is ok to use that without false. The Datetime will be convert to UTC Time when you retrieved it in codes.

Comment: Refer to Edit_3 : This is creating the purchase table using new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath)) without the false. When insert DateTime Data, then I use new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath,false) -- this has false. am I correct?

Comment: No. No matter creating the table or inserting data or query the data. `new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath,false) ` should always be used.

Comment: @Xia: OK. This means creating table using the SQLitePlatformWinRT with false parameter. when insert date of Datetime datatype into table (like public string PurchaseDate { get; set; },)  use the same SQLitePlatfromWinRT with false parameter, this will convert the date into SQLite String format (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss) like in Edit_2. Thanks

Comment: @Xia: Thanks. it works. I have created another thread related to this to thread to avoid confusion on DateTime issue. Hope you can share your thought,here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177071/how-sqlite-net-pcl-handle-utc-time