# How SQLite.Net-PCL handle UTC time

Tags: sqlite, winrt-xaml, uwp

I am using below code:

using new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath) to get SQLiteConnection 
and create table.

Class contain DateTime DataType

```
class Transaction 
    {
        [SQLite.Net.Attributes.PrimaryKey, SQLite.Net.Attributes.AutoIncrement]
        public int QId { get; set; }
        public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }  
        public int Amount {get;set;}
        Public string ItemCode {get;set;}      
    }
```

Insert Data As follows:

```
var db = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath);

 var newItem = new Transaction()
  {  
     PurchaseDate = DateTime.Now,            
     Amount = 100,
     ItemCode = "Abc-C10"               
  };

 db.Insert(newItem);
```

The date will be stored as Ticks(e.g. 636071680313888433) and this is UTC time.

1) using above DateTime.Now, If my Computer time setting is

1a) in British Time,

will the above code : purchase = DateTime.Now  be converted correctly?

1b) in Usa Time,

will the above code : purchase = DateTime.Now  be converted correctly?

How to handle this tick in SQL-statement?

How to select all transaction from ,say, a date range ? say , 2016-07-10  to 2016-07-20 ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "converted correctly"? The most correct behaviour is no conversion.

Answer (score 3):

The safest way to work with dates is to use the `DateTimeOffset` type instead of `DateTime`.

`DateTime` does not contain the information about the time zone in which it was created, all it knows is whether it is in UTC or local time, which is not enough if the data is going to be used in different locations.

`DateTimeOffset` contains not only the time and date information, but also the time zone, which means the result will always be what you expect.

There are no differences in the way it is used, just change the type:

```
class Transaction 
{
    [SQLite.Net.Attributes.PrimaryKey, SQLite.Net.Attributes.AutoIncrement]
    public int QId { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset PurchaseDate { get; set; }  
    public int Amount {get;set;}
    Public string ItemCode {get;set;}      
}
```

For database access:

```
var db = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(
   new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath);

var newItem = new Transaction()
  {  
     PurchaseDate = DateTimeOffset.Now, //or use DateTimeOffset.UtcNow for UTC datetime           
     Amount = 100,
     ItemCode = "Abc-C10"               
  };

 db.Insert(newItem);
```

Comment: How to select the date range when Sqlite contain UTC time. Can show me how this is done.

Comment: This doesn't work, If I use a DateTimeOffset and save it to sqlite-net then when I retriever it that offset got lost and has been converted to the equivalent with zero offset. So it entirely poinless to use this.

Answer (score 1):

> 1a) in British Time, will the above code : purchase = DateTime.Now be converted correctly?
>
> 1b) in Usa Time,
> will the above code : purchase = DateTime.Now be converted correctly?

By "convert correctly" if you mean convert to the correct time value, the answer is yes. It will be convert to the UTC time using ticks.

> How to handle this tick in SQL-statement?
>
> How to select all transaction from ,say, a date range ? say , 2016-07-10 to 2016-07-20 ?

The convertion from ticks to other time units is like below:

- Ticks per day:            864,000,000,000
- Ticks per hour:            36,000,000,000
- Ticks per minute:             600,000,000
- Ticks per second:              10,000,000
- Ticks per millisecond:             10,000

So you can use the SQL-Statement like below to get the data from 2016-07-10 to 2016-07-20:

```
SELECT min(PurchaseDate) as 'Date',sum(Qty) as 'Size' from Purchase 
group by (PurchaseDate/(864000000000*10)) //864000000000*10 = 1day*10
order by PurchaseDate
```

**Update:** If you want to select the Date between 2016-07-10 and 2016-07-20, you can use the following SQL-statement:

```
select strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',purchaseDate/10000000 - 62135596800,'unixepoch') as 'date' from purchase where date between '2016-07-10' and '2016-07-20'
```

Comment: @Xia: How to select date Between 2016-07-10 and 2016-07-20 ? Select min(PurchaseDate) as 'Date', sum(Amount) from Purchase Between  " " And " " . How to express the date inside the double quote " " ?

Comment: You can't express date inside double quote in SQLite. For select between 2016-07-10 and 2016-07-20, please see my update.

Comment: @Xia: I will come back here soon. Thank u a lot . I will work hard on this project to showcase microsoft UWP-based App. I hope I can use some cool Controls and UI for this SQLite Data Presentation.

Comment: @Xia: On the same SQLite, I have this question for trend analysis using SQLite. here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487681/how-to-create-1000-rows-in-a-table-once-only   please help.